# Display Template Error

Tags: 2013, web-part, display-template

I've customised a display template for a catalogue of images, and upon clicking the thumbnail, I want the image to download.

So I changed the script from:

```
<div class="zoom-pictureOnTopImageContainer" id="_#= pictureContainerId =#_">
            <a class="cbs-pictureImgLink" href="_#= linkURL =#_" title="_#= $htmlEncode(line1) =#_" id="_#= pictureLinkId =#_">_#= pictureMarkup =#_
```

To:

```
<a class="cbs-pictureImgLink" href="_#= linkURL =#_" title="_#= $htmlEncode(line1) =#_" id="_#= pictureLinkId =#_" download="_#= pictureURL =#_">_#= pictureMarkup =#_
```

So I added download and to name it the picture URL.

It works great in Chrome and I was very happy. Checked it in and now my users just get **Something Went Wrong** where the display template should be.

If I take the download part out, the template works again for my users.  I could understand if it didn't work at all, but as an administrator, it works for me, just not my users - very strange.

To add, just in case it's not obvious :-) I'm still a newbie with SharePoint, but have HTML experience with a little javascript and it's driving me insane trying to work it out, so please help

~

Comment: What browser are you're "users" using? The download attribute is only supported in modern browsers and not IE 11 e.g.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I double checked as I mostly use Chrome and it downloads in Chrome, but in IE it opens in a new window which is still fine. Just doesn't work for my users - that kind of error I would expect to have forgotten to publish, just doesn't make sense. I'm getting a full crawl run to see if makes a difference.

Comment: Np. It was worth a shot since https://caniuse.com/#feat=download says it's not supported in IE. Can you instead check with you're users what error is thrown in the developer tools console?